# Need help creating a compound interest calculator

Tags: python

I'm trying out making a compound interest calculator, managed to make one work but I'm now trying to add a part where the user inputs an amount they want to get their account to and then find the amount of years until they reach the goal. I want my output to be the amount of money in the account next to the amount of years it took to get there, plus all previous years outputs.I'm not really sure how to make the loop for this, any help?
Code so far:

```
percent = float(input("Interest %: "))
Interest = float((percent + 100) / 100)
money = float(input("How much did you originally have in the bank?"))
num_years = float(input("How many years has it been in the bank?"))
Total_money = float((Interest ** num_years) * money)

while Total_money < 1000000:
    num_years += 1
    print([Total_money, num_years])
    if Total_money >= 1000000:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

As it goes through the for loop, you need to change the amount of total_money:

```
percent = float(input("Interest %: "))
Interest = float((percent + 100) / 100)
money = float(input("How much did you originally have in the bank?"))
num_years = float(input("How many years has it been in the bank?"))
Total_money = float((Interest ** num_years) * money)

while Total_money < 1000000:
    num_years += 1
    Total_money *= Interest
    print([Total_money, num_years])
    if Total_money >= 1000000:
        break
```

The line `Total_money *= Interest` is the same as:

```
Total_money = Total_money * interest
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
percent = float(input("Interest %: "))
Interest = float((percent + 100) / 100)
money = float(input("How much did you originally have in the bank?"))
num_years = float(input("How many years has it been in the bank?"))

n=0
while n < num_years:
    Total_money = float((Interest ** n) * money)
    n += 1
    print(round(Total_money, 2), n)
    if Total_money >= 1000000:
        break
```